# Question on invoking another macro_rules in macro_rules definition

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm implementing writing TLV packet to somewhat impl `std::io::Write`.

First I implement `WriteBE<T>` trait, whose `write_be(&mut self, data: T)` method can write data with type `T` to `Self`. (implementation details omitted)

And I'm trying to use macro_rules! to implement calculation of total packet length in compile time (because most packets have fixed length in my case). macros are as follows:

```rust
macro_rules! len_in_expr {
    (
        self.write_be( $data: expr $(,)? ) $(?)? $(;)*
    ) => {
        std::mem::size_of_val(&$data)
    };
    (
        write_be(self, $data: expr $(,)? ) $(?)? $(;)*
    ) => {
        std::mem::size_of_val(&$data)
    };
    (
        $other: expr
    ) => {
         0
    };
}

/// calculate total write size in block
macro_rules! tlv_len_in_block {
    ({
        $( $e: expr );* $(;)?
    }) => {
        0 $(
            + ( len_in_expr!($e) )
        )*
    };
}
```

But when I calculating total length like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5185087a997c9b27e5d42db0f2b6ca60):

```rust
fn main() {
    let y = tlv_len_in_block!({
        write_be(self, 0u32,)?;
    });
    println!("y={}", y);
}
```

I get a result `0`.

If I comment the `$other: expr` match arm, I get a compile error:

```rust
6  |   macro_rules! len_in_expr {
   |   ------------------------ when calling this macro
...
30 |               + ( len_in_expr!($e) )
   |                                ^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
...
39 |       let y = tlv_len_in_block!({
   |  _____________-
40 | |         write_be(self, 0u32,)?;
41 | |     });
   | |______- in this macro invocation
```

What's the problem with my code? And how can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I can understand, the problem is that you have one token `$e` in `tlv_len_in_block!` and that one token can no longer be broken into individual tokens in `len_in_expr!`. I am not an expert in macros so I could be wrong here though.

Comment: Note that the full expression will be evaluated before `size_of_val()` takes it. It may cause double evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once metavariables inside `macro_rules!` are captured into some fragment specifier (e.g. `expr`), they cannot be decomposed anymore. Quoting [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#transcribing):

> When forwarding a matched fragment to another macro-by-example, matchers in the second macro will see an opaque AST of the fragment type. The second macro can't use literal tokens to match the fragments in the matcher, only a fragment specifier of the same type. The ident, lifetime, and tt fragment types are an exception, and can be matched by literal tokens. The following illustrates this restriction:
>
> ```rust
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:expr) => { bar!($l); }
> // ERROR:               ^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>     (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```
>
> The following illustrates how tokens can be directly matched after matching a tt fragment:
>
> ```rust
> // compiles OK
> macro_rules! foo {
>     ($l:tt) => { bar!($l); }
> }
>
> macro_rules! bar {
>     (3) => {}
> }
>
> foo!(3);
> ```

Once `tlv_len_in_block!()` captured `write_be(self, 0u32,)?` inside `$e`, it cannot be decomposed into `write_be(self, $data:expr $(,)? ) and thus, cannot be matched by the second case of the` len_in_expr!()` macro, as it should have been.

There are generally two solutions to this problem:

The first is, if possible, decomposing them from the beginning. The problem is that this is not always possible. In this case, for example, I don't see a way for that to work.

The second way is much more complicated and it is using the [Push-down Accumulation](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/push-down-acc.html) technique together with [tt Munching](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html).

The idea is as follows: instead of parsing the input as whole, we parse each piece one at a time. Then, recursively, we forward the parsed bits and the yet-to-parse bit to ourselves. We also should have a stop condition on an empty input.

Here is how it will look like in your example:

```rust
macro_rules! tlv_len_in_block_impl {
    // Stop condition - no input left to parse.
    (
        parsed = [ $($parsed:tt)* ]
        rest = [ ]
    ) => {
        $($parsed)*
    };
    (
        parsed = [ $($parsed:tt)* ]
        rest = [
            self.write_be( $data:expr $(,)? ) $(?)? ;
            $($rest:tt)*
        ]
    ) => {
        tlv_len_in_block_impl!(
            parsed = [
                $($parsed)*
                + std::mem::size_of_val(&$data)
            ]
            rest = [ $($rest)* ]
        )
    };
    (
        parsed = [ $($parsed:tt)* ]
        rest = [
            write_be(self, $data:expr $(,)? ) $(?)? ;
            $($rest:tt)*
        ]
    ) => {
        tlv_len_in_block_impl!(
            parsed = [
                $($parsed)*
                + std::mem::size_of_val(&$data)
            ]
            rest = [ $($rest)* ]
        )
    };
}

/// calculate total write size in block
macro_rules! tlv_len_in_block {
    ({
        $($input:tt)*
    }) => {
        tlv_len_in_block_impl!(
            parsed = [ 0 ]
            rest = [ $($input)* ]
        )
    };
}
```

(Note that this is not exactly the same as your macro - mine *requires* a trailing semicolon, while in yours it's optional. It's possible to make it optional here, too, but it will be much more complicated.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28488d09d3df26ef8e3bb29804f5ab50).